# Cobbler in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, software-installation, cobbler

Im trying to install [cobbler](https://cobbler.github.io/) software, but unable to find the right commands to install on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. In one of the commands i found in google there it was unable to find a cobbler package in Ubuntu list of packages.
I tried to install from the git hub source also, but still facing difficulty in installing cobbler.

Answer (score 1):

A search in https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/allpackages shows your version of Ubuntu doesn't have a package for Cobbler, although [it did have one in 2013](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cobbler/Installation).  Therefore, you will need to d[ownload source from the Cobbler web site](https://cobbler.github.io/downloads/3.0.x.html) to match your current version of Ubuntu, then compile and build it following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware

Answer (score 0):

You could try [the next build snapshot](https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3APharaoh_Atem%3Acobbler-dev&package=cobbler) as stated [here](https://github.com/cobbler/cobbler/issues/1941):

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Pharaoh_Atem:/cobbler-dev/xUbuntu_18.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:Pharaoh_Atem:cobbler-dev.list"
wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:Pharaoh_Atem:cobbler-dev/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cobbler
```

But it states it's for xUbuntu, so maybe, it could require `xubuntu-desktop`. Package also could be downloaded by [link](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Pharaoh_Atem:/cobbler-dev/xUbuntu_18.04/all/cobbler_3.1.0~git.20191226.1577397150.c46abca1-15ubuntu18.04.2_all.deb) and installed by `sudo apt install /home/user/Downloads/cobbler*.deb`. Working download link could be found when you click **the next build snapshot** link. But replace this path by your real path to the `.deb` installer.